# Having problems to find an equation for radioisotope production yield

Tags: particle-physics, radioactivity, particle-accelerators

I'm trying to find the required target mass for a specific nuclear reaction with a fixed yield and cross-section.

I am trying to get a plot, or a result for target like this:
[image: Graph 1]

I've found some equations for my requested results, but they are from the same person's articles and I couldn't find another source. I've searched for EOB and TTY calculations but couldn't really mde something.

[image]

[image: Equation 2]

Could you help me with the wanted results? What equation should I use?

29.4 TBq
0.05 barns
45 (target molar mass)
59.1 years (produced radionuclide half-life)

Comment: Anyone interested?